# read text from scroll Textview and insert specific string in macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

Hi I want to create a string based on user input in MacOS, swift.

for example, if the user has input a string

"
Line 1 fadsjkf

Line 2 fasdjkfla

Line 3 fasdnfkdf

"

I would like to read the string in each line and insert some characters or string like

"
XYZ Line 1 fadsjkf

ABC Line 2 fasdjkfla

DEF Line 3 fasdnfkdf

"

How to realize this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, is the user input on 3 lines ? If so, you cou split the string in an array, add the text at the beginning of each item and recompose a string.

Would be like this:

```
let someText = """
Line 1 fadsjkf
Line 2 fasdjkfla
Line 3 fasdnfkdf
"""
// May be your text comes as let someText = "Line 1 fadsjkf\nLine 2 fasdjkfla\nLine 3 fasdnfkdf"

let toBeAppended = ["XYZ", "ABC", "DEF"] // Do you want to compute automatically ?
var lines = someText.split(separator: "\n").map { String($0) }
var newLines = ""

for (iLine, line) in lines.enumerated() {
    let newLine = toBeAppended[iLine] + " " + line
    newLines = newLines + newLine + "\n"
}
print(newLines)
```

and get:

```
XYZ Line 1 fadsjkf
ABC Line 2 fasdjkfla
DEF Line 3 fasdnfkdf
```

EDITED

If you want more than 3 and undetermined number of lines:

```
let someText = "Line 1 fadsjkf\nLine 2 fasdjkfla\nLine 3 fasdnfkdf\nLine 4 fasdjkflaa\nLine 5 fasdjkflab\nLine 6 fasdjkflac\nLine 7 fasdjkflad\nLine 8 fasdjkflae\nLine 9 fasdjkflaf\nLine 10 fasdjkflag\nLine 11 fasdjkflah\nLine 12 fasdjkflai"
let toBeAppended = ["XYZ", "ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO", "PQR", "STU", "VWX", "YZ@"] // 9 here, up to you to add more ; beyond this, add for instance @@@
var lines = someText.split(separator: "\n").map { String($0) }
var newLines = ""

for (iLine, line) in lines.enumerated() {
    let newLine = iLine < toBeAppended.count ? toBeAppended[iLine] + " " + line : "@@@ " + line
    newLines = newLines + newLine + "\n"
}
print(newLines)
```

You get:

```
XYZ Line 1 fadsjkf
ABC Line 2 fasdjkfla
DEF Line 3 fasdnfkdf
GHI Line 4 fasdjkflaa
JKL Line 5 fasdjkflab
MNO Line 6 fasdjkflac
PQR Line 7 fasdjkflad
STU Line 8 fasdjkflae
VWX Line 9 fasdjkflaf
YZ@ Line 10 fasdjkflag
@@@ Line 11 fasdjkflah
@@@ Line 12 fasdjkflai
```

Comment: Hi, It works. However, I need a bit more complicated, actually, I don't know if the user will enter 3 lines or 5 lines. Can you deal with this?

Comment: The question for this is: how do you define the words to add at the beginning ?

Comment: I think I got it. The words to add at the beginning is only depending on the line number, but it is possible to write a function based on the [variable lines]. Thanks!

Comment: I understand that "var lines = someText.split(separator: "\n").map { String($0) }" is used to split multiple line text, but can you explain what is ".map { String($0) }" used for?

Comment: map is because split returns substrings and not strings. So for further use, map transforms substring types into strings, in case type matters. But in this case it is not needed, appending will work anyway.